# Android remote code loading

Tags: android, auto-update

I am developing a library for Android that requires frequent updates from a central server. I was thinking how nice it would be if my library could update itself -- or if I could just release a bootstrap library that downloads the target library when the app is installed.

I see this class in 1.5 called "DexClassLoader" but there seems to be precious little on the web besides the API docs. Has anyone used this successfully for the scenario which I described?

Also, do the terms of the Android Market permit such a thing?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I've successfully used [DexClassLoader](http://developer.android.com/reference/dalvik/system/DexClassLoader.html). It's important to provide a `dexOutputDir` that is actually writeable by your app, so **not** `/data/dalvik-cache`. Otherwise the log will show one or two lines about failing to write there, followed by `ClassNotFoundException`.

```
cl = new DexClassLoader("/full/path/com.example.apk",
                        getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath(),// /data/data/foo/files
                        null,  // native lib path, I haven't used this
                        MyClass.class.getClassLoader());
// This doesn't make Class.forName() work, instead I do this:
Class<?> foo = cl.loadClass("com.example.foo");
```

To make `Class.forName()` work, you could try [Thread.setContextClassLoader()](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Thread.html#setContextClassLoader(java.lang.ClassLoader)) (I haven't).

Comment: Hello can you please add complete source code.It will be a great help.Thanks in advance.

Comment: it is not work for android5 lollipop and above because of ART: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27349097/load-dex-file-dynamically-on-android-5-0

Answer (score 3):

Indeed what you want is supported and works. **DexClassLoader** is not working as expected for me, but the following code works fine.

```
DexFile df = new DexFile(new File("/data/app/my_downloaded_lib.apk"));
ClassLoader cl = getClassLoader();
Class clazz = df.loadClass("com/my/lib/MyClass", cl);
```

About the market question, i don't see any issue with this, but you have to read the EULA to be sure.

Comment: This works, but making a File object is counterproductive: DexFile will take the path and open it itself. You could use the constructor that takes a String path.

Comment: Hello, maybe you are right, but when i answered, this was the only way it works.

Answer (score 2):

`DexClassLoader` is the right answer.  Applications should never use `DexFile` directly (it's meant to be used by class loaders).

You could use external storage (`/sdcard`), or the app's private data area, for the `dexOutputDir` parameter.  External storage is usually larger, but if the card is ejected your app will be killed, and due to the lack of file permission enforcement it's easy for a third party to replace your code.  This can allow malicious apps to cause your app to perform arbitrary actions.  (If you want to do it anyway, get the path via `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()`; requires the `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permission.)

The app-private data area (get the path from `Context.getFilesDir()`) is more secure, and also has the advantage of being cleaned up automatically if the app is uninstalled.  This is the recommended approach.

Comment: I would also think that loading code off the SD card would be somewhat insecure.

Comment: NEVER write your dex file to the SD Card path. This will create a security vulnerability. http://www.symantec.com/connect/blogs/android-class-loading-hijacking

Comment: Updated to address security concerns.