# Override a class method from a string with byte-buddy?

Tags: java, android, antlr4, byte-buddy

Let's say I have the following class (or can it be done with an interface also ?) :

```
class MyCustomClass {
    boolean myCustomMethod(int a, int b){}
}
```

And the following string :

```
Math.abs(a - b) >= 10;
```

Is there a way, with Byte Buddy, to inject the code from the string into a  new subclass of MyCustomClass, in the method myCustomMethod ? Even if the String is processed with ANTLR before ?

So I get

```
class MyCustomClass_SubClassInstance extends MyCustomClass {
    // I know that with ByteBuddy, all this "ceremonial" code is not needed.
    boolean myCustomMethod(int a, int b){
         Math.abs(a - b) >= 10; // Injected code from the string
    }
}
```

Comment: how is this: Math.abs(a - b) >= 10; a String?

Comment: No, int. My question need clarification indeed.

Comment: I appreciate the super quick comeback ;-)

Comment: Yes, thanks again. Now, I must find a way to do this in Android, if it is possible with Dalvik.

Comment: Maybe there : https://stackoverflow.com/a/9527831/662618

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are going down the wrong way. Why use ByteBuddy to generate class code?!

Instead: use the [JavaCompiler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21544446/how-do-you-dynamically-compile-and-load-external-java-classes) feature to simply *build* that class as Java source - then compile it, then use the "dynamically" compiled class.

Meaning: you are somehow overcomplicating things. You actually know what you want to end up with - so *create* that as java source, and programmatically turn to `javac` to turn that into byte code.

For Android, the [JavaSourceToDex](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/cts/+/080be6f/tools/dex-tools/test/dex/reader/util/JavaSourceToDexUtil.java) class might be the thing to use.

Comment: Thanks, I think I've understood what you mean. My goal is simply to read code from file, and inject it into a subclass anonymous instance (or into an instance of a named subclass) : overall into an android project. So maybe the ByteBuddy library is not suitable for that. Looking at JavaCompiler example. (Edit : seems that the JavaCompiler is the way to go : thank you very much).

Comment: However this method cannot be used for android : there is no class javax.tools.JavaCompiler

Comment: @loloof64 Not being an android super guru, i still found something that looks promising. See my updated answer.

Comment: Thank you. I'm having a look at it.

Answer (score 2):

This is not the idea behind Byte Buddy. The Byte Buddy way of doing such a thing would be to implement a class that offers the method you want to invoke and then you generate a proxy to delegate to this method invocation from the instrumented type.

Javassist offers such functionaltiy but performance-wise, it is not great to compile strings at runtime so I would try to avoid this at all costs. Especially on Android where you typically have limited ressources. Class generation is quite expensive.

Comment: Thank you for this clarification. Meanwhile generating code from String is an important feature that I need, and I will try with DexMaker, as Kotlin does not support metaprogramming and I need a way for users to make their own function (or lambda) from a file. Because what I try to achieve is impossible otherwise. Anyway thank you for pointing me this limitation :)

Comment: Finally, I'll follow your advice of not compiling strings at runtime with a bytecode manipulator, as I found a better way to fill my needs : thanks to ANTLR4 and a custom class hierarchy and evaluator function. Thank again for pointing me that my idea was way too bad for Android system, making me reconsider my strategy.