# Does Android ART support runtime dynamic class loading just like Dalvik?

Tags: android, code-generation, dalvik, art-runtime

Currently, it's [possible](http://android-developers.blogspot.de/2011/07/custom-class-loading-in-dalvik.html) to dynamically load `.dex` classfiles into Android's Dalvik VM. This could probably also be used for [dynamic code generation at runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2610995/dynamically-generating-dalvik-bytecode-into-a-running-dalvik-android-application).

Is this still possible with the [upcoming ART runtime](https://source.android.com/devices/tech/dalvik/art.html)?

Comment: The documentation for ART is quite sparse at the moment. If you don't mind waiting, I suggest you watch [this upcoming session at I/O 2014](https://www.google.com/events/io/schedule/session/b750c8da-aebe-e311-b297-00155d5066d7) :)

Comment: unfortunately it look like not possible: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27349097/load-dex-file-dynamically-on-android-5-0

Comment: @gturedi: The question you linked to now has an answer which claims to work.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It seems to work just like it did with Dalvik.

Thanks to matiash for referencing the I/O 2014 talk! I've watched [the video recording](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EBlTzQsUoOw) of it, and here is what the developers have to say on runtime code loading (taken from the transcript):

> [Question from the audience:] So I was wondering how ART is going to
>   jive[?] with byte code injection that might happen right after
>   compilation or even at runtime.
>
> [...]
>
> [Answer by Ian Rogers:] So the model that Dalvik has and ART continues
>   is that for class loaders, we have to have everything that the class
>   loader has backed up by a file. So Dalvik never had supports for the
>   kind of doing end memory injection of instructions, and so on.
>
> If you have a file on the disk, then this is something we can do ahead
>   of time compilation for and put into our cache so that we're not
>   regenerating it all of the time. So basically, it works the same way
>   as with Dalvik.

Comment: it is not work for android5 lollipop and above because of ART: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27349097/load-dex-file-dynamically-on-android-5-0

Comment: @gturedi: The question you linked to now has an answer which claims to work.