# Android self-modifying code in ART

Tags: android, c, android-ndk, self-modifying, android-runtime

I'm trying to implement self-modifying code in my Android application using JNI.

I have the following method in MainActivity class of my application:

```
public int methodToModify()
{       
    return 42;
}
```

And this is a bytecode of this method:

```
const/16 v0, 0x2A
return v0
```

That's how this method is represented in classes.dex file:

13 00 2A 00 0F 00

My goal here is to change the return value of method `methodToModify` in a runtime from a native code. So, this is the algorithm of JNI method which implements self-modifying code:

1. Read process memory(here's a more information about this [Understanding Linux /proc/id/maps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1401359/understanding-linux-proc-id-maps)):

   `FILE *fp;
    fp = fopen("/proc/self/maps", "r");`
2. Detect the addresses of the beginning and the end of a .dex file(or an .oat file in a case of ART):

   `while (fgets(line, 2048, fp) != NULL) {
       // search for 'dex' or 'oat'
       if (strstr(line, ".oat") != NULL || strstr(line, ".dex") != NULL)
           // get starting and ending addresses of the DEX file region`
3. Find bytes of `methodToModify` in the .dex or .oat file.
4. Use `mprotect` function to set permission to write a file.
5. Modify the return value method.

My issue is that this approach perfectly works on my Nexus 7 with Android 4.2, but it doesn't work on Nexus 5 with Android 5.1. I'm able to implement self-modifying code with Dalvik, but I can't do the same with ART.

So, is it possible to implement self-modifying code with ART?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given that ART is using Ahead of Time Compilation, https://source.android.com/devices/tech/dalvik/

I'm not sure how you expected this to work since at runtime it is already in CPU architecture code and not DEX bytecode.

more details here: https://source.android.com/devices/tech/dalvik/configure.html

Google IO 2014 video on ART runtime:
https://youtu.be/EBlTzQsUoOw

Comment: As far as I understand, .oat file contains application's bytecode, but this bytecode isn't executable. In the same time, .oat file also contains native instructions transformed from bytecode, which are executable. Am I right?

Comment: @Floyd That sounds correct. The native instructions would be in the ELF file. The IO video has a description of the process.

Comment: How do you think, is it possible to change executable ART code in runtime?

Comment: I can think of two possible ways - 1) depend on dynamic class loading to change what you want (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23739261/does-android-art-support-runtime-dynamic-class-loading-just-like-dalvik), which isn't quite what you are asking as I think the different classes would just be pre-compiled, and 2) Try to alter the ELF file but that would require changing the actual x86/ARM/MIPS instructions - it would probably depend on how invasive your change is - but as runtime code changes seems not to be official supported - I don't know if that is a security violation.