# how to load xml layout file in android from sd card

Tags: android, android-layout, android-emulator

I want to load android XML layout file in my activity from sd card of my android device?
Is this possible?
Any help is appreciated.

Edit:
Actually my requirements is to have layout on sd card so i can modify it whenever i want and the changes will show in my layout.

Comment: my activity from sd card???

Answer (score 1):

Loading `XML Layout` File from `SD CARD` is simply impossible because

1. `XML Layout` file resources need to generate id with `R.java-Java Generated File` which can be generated at compile time only. You can generate if you simple copy that `XML Layout`from your SD-CARD to `res/layout/` folder at time of writing your application
2. `R.java-Java Generated` file is needed to wired up the `Java code` and `XML Layout` file. If you have used that `XML Layout` file `resources e.g[Button,EditText etc..,]` in your application.

Comment: can i get xml layout file from other apk file that was already on sd card?......just trying other option

Comment: @rajG you can definitely get the xml files from another apk package. `But they are just useless in your application`. As that `XML Layout File never been complied with your application.`

Comment: @rajG May be these link help you in some way to achieve your goal : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1001944/android-remote-code-loading

Answer (score 1):

Not possible, because xml layouts are compiled in a specific format. You would need to compile the xml and inject it in the apk, which is not feasible on the device itself.